# How to use gradient descent on data that has string values?

Tags: machine-learning, octave

I want to solve the predicting house pricing problem (https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques/data)

How could I transform string data into numerical data in Octave?

Comment: https://towardsdatascience.com/smarter-ways-to-encode-categorical-data-for-machine-learning-part-1-of-3-6dca2f71b159

Comment: Unless I'm doing something wrong the dataset you reference requires a user login. Interpreting your question literally without seeing the data I think you may find the answer at: https://octave.org/doc/v6.1.0/String-Conversions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link is paywalled, but its title mentions the word 'categorical', so I'm assuming that by 'numerical' you mean integer labels, rather than parsing a string that represents a number to its equivalent float.

So with that in mind, here's a typical way to represent this.

```
Indices = [ 1,2,3,2,3,2,1,2,1,2,3,1,3,3,1 ];
Labels  = { 'class1', 'class2', 'class3' };
```

It really is as simple as that. If you really want this to be a single 'variable', you can collect it into a struct:

```
MyCategoricalVariable = struct( 'indices', Indices, 'labels', Labels );
```

Obviously it depends how the data is provided to you in the first place. If you're given the strings instead of the labels, you can convert it to an indices/labels pair like so:

```
Data = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b' };
Labels = unique( Data );
[~, Indices] = ismember( Data, Labels )
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities of string data

1. Just one or two words, and value of test won't change (i.e. for a column it would take fix value of text), then you can use Labels. that would solve your problem.
2. if you have column which can take any value and length is also not fixed, you can first do TF-IDF and based on it you can train your model.